# dynamically render table in twig

Tags: php, laravel, twig

I am familiar with how to render table in twig but have this data in array that i can not figure out how to render it in a twig table.

```
 $data = [
    'product' => $product,
    'qty'     => $qty,
    'price'   => $price,
    'total'   => $total,
];
```

the above are in array so if i do something like

```
{% for product in products %}
{{ products }}
{% endfor %}
```

it displays all this records in products.
Now in twig table trying to render it means i have to do multiple for loops which does not work as it is supposed to. For instance

```
{% for product in product %}
 <tr>

            <td>{{ product }}</td>

        </tr>
{% endfor %}
       {% for price in price %} 
         <tr>

            <td >{{ price }}</td>

        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The above just displays it on one row
Really confused how to output something like this in a twig table

Comment: you are feeding the wrong variable across.   when you try to do `for product in products` you need a `products` variable - the "product" becomes dynamically created.   "products" would need to be an array for this to work of course

Answer (score 0):

Product is an element inside the array so you should use something like `data.product` instead of just product

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<table>
{% for dat in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ dat.product }}</td>
    <td>{{ dat.qty }}</td>
    <td>{{ dat.price }}</td>
    <td>{{ dat.total }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```